# Command line option parsing in Ruby

Tags: ruby, linux, unix, command-line-arguments, optparse

I have a ruby script that parses command line options given to it as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'optparse'

puts 'Hello World!, This is my first ruby program'

options = {}

optparse = OptionParser.new do|opts|

  opts.banner = "Featbuild minimal trial script for command line parsing"

  options[:cpl] = nil
  opts.on('-cpl SWITCH_STATE', 'compile on or off') do|cplopt|
      options[:cpl] = cplopt
      OPT_CPL=cplopt
      puts cplopt
  end

  opts.on('-h', '--help', 'Display this screen') do
    puts opts
    exit
  end
end

optparse.parse!

output = open("mypipe", "w+")

output.puts OPT_CPL
#output.flush
```

Now the line `opts.on('-cpl SWITCH_STATE', 'compile on or off') do|cplopt|` in the above script is where I have a problem.

I believe we can do it in follwoing ways:
1.)`opts.on('--cpl SWITCH_STATE', 'compile on or off') do|cplopt|`
2.)`opts.on('-c', '--cpl SWITCH_STATE', 'compile on or off') do|cplopt|`
3.)`opts.on('-cpl SWITCH_STATE', 'compile on or off') do|cplopt|`

This is what I pass as the arguments that works:

```
$./try1.rb --cpl on
$./try1.rb -c on
```

This does not work:
    $./try1.rb -cpl on

Ruby, instead of getting 'on' as the option argument, gets 'pl', as if `$./try.rb -c pl` was specified.

I want to have the string `$./try1.rb -cpl on` be parsed in such a way that `'on'` gets passed to the block of the method `opts.on()` in `'cplopt'`.

I was referring to this tutorial: http://ruby.about.com/od/advancedruby/a/optionparser2.htm

It seems `'-cpl on'` isn't possible in Ruby? Is this so?

What other alternatve solutions can I apply over here?

Answer (score 1):

Try [Trollop](https://rubygems.org/gems/trollop), as it makes option parsing life easier.

```
require 'trollop'
opts = Trollop::options do
  version "compile 0.1.0"
  banner  "Usage: compile <option> - where [options] are:"
  opt     :cpl,  "compile on or off",  :type => :string,  :default => "off"
end
puts opts.cpl
```

When run, results in:

```
$ ruby ./trollop.rb --cpl on
on

$ ruby ./trollop.rb --cpl off
off

$ ruby ./trollop.rb -c on
on

$ ruby ./trollop.rb -c off
off

$ ruby ./trollop.rb
off
```

Trollop 2.0 supports [`no-` negation of boolean options](http://masanjin.net/blog/trollop-2.0-released) which you might find easier than dealing with the `on/off` strings.

```
opt "cpl", "Compile", :default => true
```

When run, results in:

```
$ ruby trollop.rb --cpl
true

$ ruby trollop.rb --no-cpl
false
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you will need to ensure that only cp1 is in the single quotes instead of

> -cpl SWITCH_STATE

do

```
 opts.on('-cpl', 'compile on or off') do|cplopt|
  options[:cpl] = cplopt
  OPT_CPL=cplopt
  puts cplopt
 end
```

Here is an example:

```
opts.on('-s', '--size 1G or 1024M', '1G or 1024M') do |s|
    options[:size] = s;
end
```

Comment: This is what I tried:
`opts.on('-c', '--cpl SWITCH_STATE', 'compile on or off')`

`$./try1.rb -cpl on`

This results in 'pl' being read in as the argument into `options[:cpl]`